# Configuring hazelcast on a docker overlay network

Tags: docker, hazelcast

I am trying to configure hazelcast on a docker overlay network

I am programmatically configuring hazelcast with TcpIpConfig enabled and MulticastConfig disabled.
I do have a list of all the docker container assigned ip addresses to add as members to a 3 container hazelcast cluster.

When I add the 3 ip addresses as members and also add the same ip addresses as interfaces, within each container, then the cluster works fine.
However, if I do not add each ip address as an interface but I add a wild card interface that fits all 3 of the docker ip addresses then the cluster fails.

I cannot run in production with each ip address added as an interface, as a node failure will cause docker swarm to create a new hazelcast container with another ip address, and the cluster fails as a 'named' interface no longer exists.

I realize that there is a lot of underlying info behind my explanation.
I am very happy to provide code or additional info if required. (The code is very simple - with standard hazelcast ip config)

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your outside system? Do you run any service discovery like Eureka or Consul?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not using any outside system, just docker swarm for discovery. I have managed to solve the problem.

Comment: I guess it would be of benefit for the question if you add an answer yourself, in case others end up with the same issue :)

Comment: The solution was quite simple. I added the following line of code join.getTcpIpConfig().setRequiredMember(null).setEnabled(true); The trick was to use the docker remote client to get the ip addresses to configure hazelcast. I am happy to provide additional info if required.